# Python2 introspection namespace

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, introspection, anti-patterns

I try python introspection in some weird manner.
For example, I have Class LoggerManager which incapsulate pool of specific loggers classes for statistic. I know this is no standard way to do it, but I can't use mixins due to my object of class SpecificLogger is serializable to json in code and I really don't want to pass self.data throw params to **init** (in this case I need to rewrite many rows code and get problem with garbage in serialization again).

```
class LoggerManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data
        self.b = SpecificLogger()
        self.c = SpecificLogger2()
        ...

class SpecificLogger(LoggerGeneral):
    def get_data(self):
        global data #now I want get object from namespace object of LoggerManager, not really global
        do_something_with_data(data)
```

I want behavior like this code with mixins:

```
import json

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'something'

    def create_pool_of_specific_objects(self):
        self.obj = B()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def do_something_with_data(self):
        print(self.data)
        self.data = 'new_data'
        print(self.data)

    def save(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, ensure_ascii=False)

    def hack_save(self):
        data_to_dumped = {x:y for x,y in self.__dict__.iteritems() if x != 'obj'}
        return json.dumps(data_to_dumped, ensure_ascii=False)



b=B()
b.create_pool_of_specific_objects()
b.do_something_with_data()
b.save() #will raise exception due to we have all stuff from instance of class A there
b.hack_save() #will work but it is very ugly and unusable with runtime modify object of A class
```

Now I wrote code with GC, but using method get_objects I have some sort of overhead, is not it?

```
import json
import gc

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'something'
        self.obj = B()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self): pass

    def do_something_with_data(self):
        for obj in gc.get_objects(): #or even for obj in globals().values()
            if isinstance(obj, A):
                print(obj.data)
                obj.data = 'new_data'
                print(obj.data)

    def save(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, ensure_ascii=False)

a=A()
b=B()
b.do_something_with_data()
b.save() #will work
```

Any suggestion to do it with introspection and not inheritance and GC overhead? Maybe python save ref to namespace above and I can get A instance in friendly manner?
Ok, guyz. Correctly asked question includes right answer itself.
All I need is:

```
import inspect
def my_method(self):
    parent_self = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['self']
    do_something_with_parent_self(parent_self)
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ok, I added code with mixins to explain what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Introspection: How to get varnames of class methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536879/python-introspection-how-to-get-varnames-of-class-methods)